# Calendar to Date issue, period with 1 year error

Tags: java, date, calendar, gettime

this is my first time asking, I couldn't find explanation in all internet, so here you go:
I'm writing a simple function to calculate the date that was x days ago, so I wrote this code that was working very ok, until today, the calculated past date was 1 year in the future, but not for all the values, only 11 days ago, the rest was ok.
If you execute this code today you'll have this output: [you can execute it here](https://ideone.com/KNAYLU)

> difference:-11
>
> 2015-12-28
>
> difference:-12
>
> 2014-12-27

As you can see, I though it was an issue parsing from Calendar to Date, also I've check that in Calendar the values were totally ok, but the moment I transfer to Date it doesn't work, I tried to do this cast manually but the functions are deprecated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(getDate(-11, "YYYY-MM-dd"));
        System.out.println(getDate(-12, "YYYY-MM-dd"));
    }
    public static String getDate(int offset, String SimpleFormat) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SimpleFormat);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, offset);
        Date todate1 = cal.getTime();
        long diff = todate1.getTime()-(new Date()).getTime();
        System.out.println("difference:"+diff/ (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        String fromdate = dateFormat.format(todate1);
        return fromdate;
    }
}
```

Later I found a nice library called [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) very nice and fast, so I changed the code to work with it, but surprise the same issue.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SimpleFormat);
DateTime today = new DateTime();
String fromdate = dateFormat.format(today.plus(Period.days(offset)).toDate());
```

So far I've also check that adding 350 days or so, into this 11 days period it gives a wrong date too.
I know I can use Joda-time formatter, but still I can't find exactly what's the problem, any help would be nice :)

(for the ones who ever had this issue):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(SimpleFormat);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't with the Date or DateTime, but rather with the formatter.

`YYYY` means the ISO Week Year.  However, the ISO Week year for the last partial week of the year [is the next year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Disadvantages).

`yyyy` means the calendar year, which is what you really wanted.

Comment: Incidentally, Twitter made this same mistake at the end of last year in their HTTP Date header... but not their HTTP Expires header.

Comment: Oh, good catch. This is a *very* good catch. I don't know how long I would have stared at that before spotting it, but it would have been quite a while.

Comment: @DavidConrad Well, if Twitter hadn't just had [the same problem](http://what.thedailywtf.com/t/twitter-time-warp/6740), I probably wouldn't have thought to check it.

Comment: @Powerlord thank you!, I wonder if some other important companies are having the same issue and they don't know it yet :D